# Can we use file.write to pull rows from a csv file and write them

Tags: python

A csv file is opened and read as

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
```

Also I opened the file

```
DM = open('DM_FILE.txt', 'w+')
```

Now I want to pull specific fields from the csv file and save in  txt file.So I am using this

```
 DM.write('row[17]+,+row[16]+,+row[25]\n')
```

But I am getting output like this.

```
 row[17]+,+row[16]+,+row[25]+,+row[18]
```

Its simple but dont know why it is not coming.Again i tried using csv.writerow which worked.But the output came with contrlM.like ^M end of each line.Some dos to unix problem I guess since I am running it in unix.Need the soln for both.

```
 DM = csv.writer(open('DM_FILE.txt', 'w+'))
 DM.writerow([row[17]+row[16]+row[25]+row[18]])
```

Also desired output is like

```
 ,J,13260,,GARMAN,,STEVE,FAIRFIELDLN,
 ,J,1,,CMA1235,,,LOCKHEED###BLVD,MZ#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'row[17]'` and `row[17]` are different in Python. The former is a string with seven characters, the latter is a 18th item in the `row` tuple.

To write given fields (specified by their indices) separated by commas into the `DM` file:

```
from operator import itemgetter

DM.write(','.join(itemgetter(17, 16, 25, 18)(row)))
DM.write('\n')
```

Or if a comma might be in any of the fields then you could use `csv` module to escape it:

```
with open('TM_FILE.txt', 'wb') as DM: # assume Python 2
    writer = csv.writer(DM, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(itemgetter(17, 16, 25, 18)(row))
```

Comment: DM.write(','.join(itemgetter(17, 16, 25, 18,20,21,19,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,8,36,35,34)(row)))
TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 18

Comment: `itemgetter()` must accept several arguments on both [Python 2](http://ideone.com/PuydV7) and [Python 3](http://ideone.com/WZ8nEz). [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25672256/edit)  and include the complete traceback. Try the code in [the links](http://ideone.com/PuydV7).

Comment: @JF I am using python 2.the solution isnt working throwing the same error.Also for 2nd part of the problem I am not having comma problem I am having ^M at every end of line as o/p in text file

Comment: @Rajarshi: 0. I don't see the traceback in your question that I've requested (many lines that contain `TypeError`). 1. have you tried [the code](http://ideone.com/PuydV7)? Does it produce the error? 2. My code uses `'\n'` (notice: `lineterminator='\n'`).

Comment: That is the only error I am having.Alos any idea why the control m is coming.

Comment: @Rajarshi: do you see a line above `TypeError` that says `Traceback (most recent call last)`? My code doesn't produce `'\r'` (may be displayed as `^M` in the terminal) on Unix  unless they are embed in `row` values (unlikely).